# Force svg to be requested as image/svg+xml

Tags: angular, apache, svg, mime-types

I have an angular application with svg icons that works fine on my localhost. However, when I upload my project to the apache server, some of the icons don't load and they are served as "text/html" instead of "image/svg+xml". The following error is logged on the console when I load the page: *"The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')."*.
All of my svgs has the line below as param for the svg tag.

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

I have also updated the .htaccess with the following info:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

My angular application files are inside the folder "teste", which is inside the folder "public_html". I have changed the .htaccess file from both directories.

What else can I do to the icons work?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have noticed that for some reason my angular app is doing the request for the assets folder that is inside "public_html", instead of using the the folder from "teste". So I just put all the icons inside this folder and now it is working.